# Sending objects to Spring-Boot's RestController Via Angular 2 and JSON

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Right now I am using a H2 database and want to register a user and see it in the database.

(BackEnd Module) Spring-Boot is running on port 8080 and Angular 2 (FrontEnd Module) is running on 3000.

(FRONTEND)

```
@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {

    constructor (private http:Http) { }

    sendUser (newUser: RegisterModel) {
        let url = "http://localhost:8080/user/register";
       // let header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

        return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(newUser)); //, {headers: header}
    }
}
```

RegisterModel

```
export class RegisterModel{
    public userId: number;
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public userName: string;
    public password: string;
    public passwordCheck:string;
    public created: Date;
}
```

RegisterComponet

```
@Component ({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'register',
    templateUrl: './register.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent {

    newUser: RegisterModel = new RegisterModel();

    constructor (private registerService: RegisterService){

    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.registerService.sendUser(this.newUser).subscribe(
            data => {

                this.newUser = new RegisterModel();
            },
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    }
}
```

(BACKEND)

```
    @RestController("/user")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
    UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User registerUser(@RequestBody User user){

        System.out.println("YAY-----------"+user.getFirstName());
        return userService.save(user);
    }
```

CORS Filter

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true); // you USUALLY want this
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

@Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Here is my directory:

[image]

Full Directory:

[image]

And the Error I am getting in the console:

[image]

I check the post response and this is what I get:

[image]

git repo

[GIT LINK](https://github.com/drewjocham/AngularIssue.git)

------------------UPDATE 1-----------------------

I updated my CorsConfig class to:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

  @Bean
  public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(false); //updated to false
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
  }

  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Error in console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/user/register. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

This is what I get when I use `Advanced REST client` via google chrome plug-in

[image]

My git repo is updated with my current code.

I plan on using spring security too once I am able to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, x-requested-with, accept, Authorization, Content-Type");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    if (!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
      try {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    } 
  }

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

  public void destroy() {}

}
```

write this filter insted of following

```
`@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
config.setAllowCredentials(false); //updated to false
config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
config.addAllowedHeader("*");
config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
return new CorsFilter(source);
```

}`

Comment: Thank you. I had to remove Spring Security for now. But now I am getting a 404 error and not 403 so that is a better error in my opinion. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CORS filter in spring boot app to allow cross browser request.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I have one I just did not include it in my question.

Comment: just pass false value to setAllowCredentials. and also allow option method

Comment: I set it to false and now I am getting the following error in the browser `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/user/register. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)` I am not sure what you mean by `"also allow option method " `